# Como puedo crear un servidor local en node para consultar una api?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

les consulto lo siguiente:

Estoy intentando consultar una api de clima (https://www.metaweather.com/api/) pero para poder consultarla me pide que lo haga desde un servidor HTTPS. Estuve googleando un poco y encontré que con NodeJS lo puedo hacer, lo que no le encuentro la vuelta es para vincular mi archivo index.html y que lo que vea en el navegador sea este.

Comment: Ya probaste usar fetch??

Comment: Si de hecho lo hice con fetch y me sale esto en la consola: 

Access to fetch at 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/2013/4/27/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Tengo entendido que esto es porque no lo estoy haciendo desde http

Comment: necesitas crear un servidor y configurar cors para poder realizar las solicitudes

Comment: puedes leer [esto](https://expressjs.com/) y guiarte para crear un servidor simple

Comment: Sii, te toca investigar de los bloqueos CORS y como mandarles headers, principalmente cuales acepta la página... Eso creo que ya te toca investigar

Comment: Gracias a todos! me voy a poner a leer bien esto.